# Outlook Calendar/Contacts Export to PST

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, imap, migration

We have a large number of imap to office365 migrations to complete.users currently use outlook for their email. O365 migration doesn’t migrate calendar/contacts etc so we are manually exporting from the existing mailbox, creating a new outlook profile for o365 then importing the pst files again.

We are looking for a way to simplify and or automate the process .

Anyone any ideas??

Comment: What are you migrating from exactly? I presume on premise Exchange server?

Comment: What do you mean by "large number of imap to office365 migrations to complete"? Why is relevant that users currently use "outlook for their email"? What exactly do you mean by O365 migration? Have you already thoroughtly searched the Microsoft resources?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you can only migrate items in a user's inbox or other mail folders for IMA mailboxes. This type of migration doesn't migrate contacts, calendar items, or tasks. I'm afraid that you can only export Outlook calendar items and Contacts items manually.

More information about migrations: [Migrate data to my Microsoft 365 for business subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/simplified-signup/migrate-data-business-standard?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.